# Hyperic SIGAR CpuTimer class: Wall-Clock time or CPU time?

Tags: java, performance, time, hyperic, sigar

Does anyone know if the SIGAR `CPUTimer` class keeps track of the wall-clock time or the cpu time spend on the program that calls it? I've searched in Google but to no avail. Their documentation also is very minimal at its best so I can't figure out whether this class uses CPU high-resolution performance timers from the CPU itself (the CPU's in which we are taking measurements have that) or it actually does a fine-grained measurement of program wall-clock time.

P.S.: And no, I am not interested in using Java's method `System.currentTimeMillis()` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can download the sigar source code and look at it yourself. The source code is not that big at all. I am sure you will be looking in to the right code in no time.